# find the general solution using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

need help with the following question:
$$y''' - y''+y'-y = e^t\sin(t)$$
It is supposed to be done using variation of parameters. I know the formulas, but the integrals make me cringe.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a bit before resorting to variation of parameters.

Let $y''(t)+y(t) = f(t)$. We then have
$$f'(t) - f(t) = e^t \sin(t) \implies e^{-t}f'(t) - e^{-t} f(t) = \sin(t)$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-t} f(t)\right) = \sin(t) \implies e^{-t} f(t) = -\cos(t) + c_1$$
Hence,
$$y''(t) + y(t) = -e^t \cos(t) + c_1 e^t$$
Now apply variation of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Integrals? What integrals? You solve the homogeneous equation, $$y'''-y''+y'-y=0$$ then you find the form of a particular solution based on the form of that $e^t\sin t$ term, then you find the coefficients in that particular solution by plugging it into the equation and doing some algebra.

Comment: I need to use variation of parameters, not undetermined coefficients

Comment: Right. Sorry. Maybe you could show us the integrals that make you cringe, and how you got to them, and we could all have a look to see what we could suggest.

Answer (score 0):

$$
D^3-D^2+D-1=\color{#C00000}{(D-1)}\color{#00A000}{(D^2+1)}
$$
Therefore, the solution to the homogeneous equation is $\color{#C00000}{a_1e^t}+\color{#00A000}{a_2\sin(t)}+\color{#00A000}{a_3\cos(t)}$.

Note that for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$
(D-1)(D^2+1)e^{\alpha t}=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+1)e^{\alpha t}
$$

---

If $\alpha=1+i$, then
$$
\color{#C00000}{\frac1{2i}}e^{\alpha t}\color{#00A000}{-\frac1{2i}}e^{\bar\alpha t}=e^t\sin(t)
$$
Furthermore, $(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+1)=\color{#C00000}{-2+i}$ and $(\bar\alpha-1)(\bar\alpha^2+1)=\color{#00A000}{-2-i}$.

Therefore, $y=c_1e^{\alpha t}+c_2e^{\bar\alpha t}$ is a solution when
$$
c_1(\color{#C00000}{-2+i})=\color{#C00000}{\frac1{2i}}\quad\text{and}\quad c_2(\color{#00A000}{-2-i})=\color{#00A000}{-\frac1{2i}}
$$
That is,
$$
c_1=\frac{-1+2i}{10}\quad\text{and}\quad c_2=\frac{-1-2i}{10}
$$
So we get
$$
y=-\tfrac15e^t\Big(\cos(t)+2\sin(t)\Big)
$$
as a particular solution.

---

The general solution is therefore
$$
y=-\tfrac15e^t\Big(\cos(t)+2\sin(t)\Big)+a_1e^t+a_2\sin(t)+a_3\cos(t)
$$